# Method Paramaters for Method type (int[] nums)

Tags: java, arrays, loops, sum, parameter-passing

I am working on a code that adds numbers in an array together and makes the sum. However, if a number is 13, that number and the number after it are skipped. I cannot get my `main()` method to input parameters into the method that I created to do this task however.
The syntax I have currently is:

```java
public static int sum13(int[] nums) {
     int sum = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
          if (nums[i] ==13 || nums[i]-- == 13) {
               continue;
          } else {
               sum += nums[i];
          }
     return sum;
     }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(sum13([1, 2, 2, 1]));
     System.out.println(sum13([13, 1, 2, 13, 3, 3]));
}

}
```

On the `System.out.println` lines, I am getting the error message,

```
The method sum13(int[]) in the type A3 is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, int, int)
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Comment: [1,2,3] is not how you create an array of ints. Correct that and you'll be fine

Comment: Why don't you use varargs instead? `sum13(int... nums)` and then `sum13(1,2,3,4)` etc.

Comment: Also think about what `nums[i]-- == 13` means. I assume you want so skip "the number after 13"... but does `nums[i]--` represent the next number? (Hint: take the expression appart, i.e. you could write it like this: `int x = nums[i]; x--; if(x ==13) ...` - what number does `x` refer to?)

Comment: Your current syntax is wrong. Did you guess that syntax? I don't think that _stackoverflow_ is the place to learn Java syntax. Did you try searching the Internet for **java int array initialization** ?

Answer (score 4):

Options:

1 - create an array, since the method is expecting one

```
sum13(new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 1};
// or
int[] array = { 1, 2, 2, 1}; // short for int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 1};
sum13(array);
```

2 - use `varargs` parameter (variable arity parameter) like:

```
public static int sum13(int... nums) {  // creates: int[] nums
```

called with:

```
sum13(1, 2, 2, 1)
```

in this case Java will create the array and pass it as `int[] nums`.

The `...` can be used with any type, but it must be the last parameter specified in the method declaration. The compiler will generate the method as if an array is passed - so it is used inside the method as an array of the specified type; the array itself is created when the method is called. Optionally an array can be given instead of the values.

---

Despite not the (direct) question, be warned that `nums[i]-- == 13` is not doing what probably was intended. The Postfix Decrement Expression `X--`, where `X` is a variable (or expression denoting one), will decrement the variable and return its value *before* it was decremented. So `nums[i]--` will return the value of `nums[i]` and decrement the value stored at index `i`. Probably it was intended to be `nums[i-1] == 13`, but that will result in an exception when `i == 0` (unless not evaluated).

Answer (score 2):

The struct of this question is very good!
The reason for this question is that the parameter of the `main` method is not applicable for the `sum13` method.
About the understood of array is a little wrong. The right solution is

```
System.out.println(sum13(new int[]{1,2,3,4}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `if`-`else` to skip the number if it is 13 and the number next to it:

```
public static int sum13(int... nums) {
     int sum = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] == 13) i++; 
        else sum += nums[i];
     }
     return sum;
}
```

Here, if the number is 13, you just increment `i` by 1. If the number at the current iteration is 13, it will not add to the `sum` because the `sum` is in the `else` part, also, it will not add the number right next to it, because you increment `i` by 1, and at the end of the loop `i` is incremented again which means `i` will effectively be incremented twice, skipping the number next to 13 if the current number is 13.

Also, I have used variable length arguments as mentioned in the other answers to allow you to pass an arbitrary number of parameters to `sum13` and therefore you call it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(sum13(1, 2, 2, 1));
     System.out.println(sum13(13, 1, 2, 13, 3, 3));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the mistakes in your code are-

1. Return statement inside a for loop.
2. Wrong declaring and passing the array to the sum13 method.
3. `nums[i]-- == 13` is not the correct way to look back for 'i-1'th element and when looking for the i-1 the element do check it does not goes below zero else you will face ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.

   ```
   public static int sum13(int[] nums) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
         if (nums[i] == 13 || ( i > 0 && nums[i-1] == 13)) {
              continue;
         }
         sum += nums[i];
     }
    return sum;
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {

     int[] array1 = {1, 2, 2, 1};
     int[] array2 = {13, 1, 2, 13, 3, 3,13,5,13,2,13,1,1,1};
     System.out.println(sum13(array1));
     System.out.println(sum13(array2));
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> We can create arrays and assingning values like below.

```
import java.util.*;
class Example{
public static void main(String args[]){
    //--------Method 1-----------------
    int[] a=new int[5];
    int[] b;
    b=new int[5];
    //int[] x=new int[]; //Illegal -->size
    
    //--------Method 2-----------------
    int[] c={10,20,30,40,50};
    int[] d;
    //d={10,20,30,40,50}; //Illegal
            
    //--------Method 3-----------------
    int[] e=new int[]{10,20,30,40,50};
    int[] f;
    f=new int[]{10,20,30,40,50}; //Legal
    
    int[] g=new int[5]{10,20,30,40,50}; //Ilelgal-->size
    }
}
```

So,In your code(passing array elements as arguments in main methode)should correct like this.`System.out.println(sum13(new int[]{1, 2, 2, 1})); System.out.println(sum13(new int[]{13, 1, 2, 13, 3, 3}));`

Other thing is nums[i]-- wrong.If we want to get i-1 element we should code as nums[i-1].So, whole code is below.

```
import java.util.*;
class Demo{
public static int sum13(int[] nums) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] == 13 || ( i > 0 && nums[i-1] == 13)) {
            continue;
        }
    sum += nums[i];
    }
 return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(sum13(new int[]{1, 2, 2, 1}));
    System.out.println(sum13(new int[]{13, 1, 2, 13, 3, 3}));
   }

}
```